# Image in djangocms-teaser

Tags: django, image, django-cms, teaser

I've got a question about functionality of `djangocms-teaser`. Is there a way to import a scaliable picture in the teaser? To make it more fancy.

For example, I've got pic 300*300 on my PC, but when I load it into teaser, it automatically (or manually) re-sizes to 50*50.

Maybe you got some ideas about how to implement that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found configurations for image and teaser in my djanjoCMS. Now thinking about how to union that two things and hardcode information about image in teaser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kek, I've found a solution for my question. 
In `teaser.html` (can be found in `site-packages-->djangocms-teaser`) added `width="***"`. 
 That made images shown in teasers smaller.